# Return in foreach showing only 1st value

Tags: php, function, foreach, return

I have problem. In my function, return shows only first player from server. I wanted to show all players from server, but i cant get this working. Here is my code:

```
function players() {
    require_once "inc/SampQueryAPI.php";
    $query = new SampQueryAPI('uh1.ownserv.pl', 25052); // Zmień dane obok! //
    if($query->isOnline())
    {
        $aInformation = $query->getInfo();
        $aServerRules = $query->getRules();
        $aPlayers = $query->getDetailedPlayers();
        if(!is_array($aPlayers) || count($aPlayers) == 0)
        {
            return 'Brak graczy online';
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($aPlayers as $sValue)   
            {
                $playerid = $sValue['playerid'];
                $playername = htmlentities($sValue['nickname']);
                $playerscore = $sValue['score'];
                $playerping = $sValue['ping'];
                return '<li>'.$playername.' (ID: '.$playerid.'), Punkty ('.$playerscore.'), Ping ('.$playerping.')</li>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You're returning from within your loop.

Instead, you should concatenate the results for each iteration and then return that concatenated string *outside* the loop.

e.g.

```
$result = "";
foreach($aPlayers as $sValue) {
   # add to $result...
}
return $result
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function players() {

    require_once "inc/SampQueryAPI.php";
    $query = new SampQueryAPI('uh1.ownserv.pl', 25052); // Zmień dane obok! //
    if($query->isOnline())
    {
         $aInformation = $query->getInfo();
         $aServerRules = $query->getRules();
         $aPlayers = $query->getDetailedPlayers();
         if(!is_array($aPlayers) || count($aPlayers) == 0)
         {
             return 'Brak graczy online';
         }
         else
         {
             $ret = '';
             foreach($aPlayers as $sValue)   
             {
                 $playerid = $sValue['playerid'];
                 $playername = htmlentities($sValue['nickname']);
                 $playerscore = $sValue['score'];
                 $playerping = $sValue['ping'];
                 $ret .=    '<li>'.$playername.' (ID: '.$playerid.'), Punkty ('.$playerscore.'), Ping ('.$playerping.')</li>'; 
             }
             return $ret;
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In a function you can only return **ONE** value.

Try creating a list of players and return the list when all records have been added to it.
In your case, list of players will result in an array of players